# How to process nested list of objects in JAVA 8 - process inner list sequentially, while the outer list has to be processed parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I am trying to solve the below situation :
I have a nested list of custom objects. I have to process the outer list parallel but the inner list objects has to be processed in sequence. I tried list.parallelstream() for the outer list and list.stream() for the inner list but it not working, the inner list values are processed randomly during execution. I thought of using Thread (ExecutorService) but not sure how exactly to start with. Below is my code snippet for the paralalStream:

Code to process the list :

```
List<List<MyObject>> masterList = getMasterList();    
masterList.parallelStream().forEach(innerList -> printSubList(innerList));
```

Code to populate the list:

```
private static List<List<MyObject>> getMasterList() {
    MyObject myObject1 = new MyObject(1,"ABC-1");
    MyObject myObject2 = new MyObject(2,"ABC-2");
    MyObject myObject3 = new MyObject(3,"ABC-3");
    MyObject myObject4 = new MyObject(1,"XYZ-1");
    MyObject myObject5 = new MyObject(2,"XYZ-2");
    
    List<MyObject> innerList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    innerList1.add(myObject1);
    innerList1.add(myObject2);
    innerList1.add(myObject3);
    
    List<MyObject> innerList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    innerList2.add(myObject4);
    innerList2.add(myObject5);                            
    List<List<MyObject>> masterList = new ArrayList<>();
    masterList.add(innerList1);
    masterList.add(innerList2);
    return masterList;
}
```

Print the object to verify :

```
private static Consumer<? super List<MyObject>> printSubList(List<MyObject> innerList) {        
    innerList.stream();
    for(MyObject myObject : innerList) {
        System.out.println("System Time = "+ System.currentTimeMillis()+" = "+myObject.getName()+" "+myObject.getId());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am open to use Thread as well, but not sure how in this situation. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is my current output :

```
System Time = 1603173228270 = ABC-3 3                                   
System Time = 1603173228271 = XYZ-1 1                                    
System Time = 1603173228272 = ABC-1 1                                   
System Time = 1603173228272 = ABC-2 2                                   
System Time = 1603173228272 = XYZ-2 2
```

But I want it to be :

```
System Time = 1603173228270 = ABC-1 1                                   
System Time = 1603173228271 = ABC-2 2                                   
System Time = 1603173228272 = ABC-3 3                                   
System Time = 1603173228270 = XYZ-1 1                                                          
System Time = 1603173228271 = XYZ-2 2
```

Comment: "I have to process the outer list parallel but the inner list objects has to be processed in sequence." That's what your current code does, is it not? What's the output of your code? How is it different to the output you expect?

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't put all that info in the comments.

Comment: Updated with desired output, @Sweeper

Comment: What you want is kind of contradictory. How can a line with an earlier system time (4th line) be printed _after_ a message with a later system time (3rd line)?

Comment: If both the inner list are processed through 2 different thread, we can achieve this right?

Comment: Was it really that ABC-3 was printed before ABC-1?

Comment: It seems like you still want to _print_ the objects in order, just that the timestamps be out of order. Well, printing them in a parallel `forEach` is not going to make them be printed in order. So you need to do a parallel `map` first, to give each sublist a non-sequential timestamp, and then do a `forEachOrdered` to print the timestamps + objects in their original order. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to reply to you.
In this case, I thought your idea that is wrong in multiple threads.
Because the process's consequence is not sure in multiple threads or the  Parallelstream, every thread executes process may be using different times. So we can not control the order in the process, exceptionally, we make some logic to them, but it is not easy, besides, it is unnecessary.
If you really want to use multiple threads to process these data. You can try to follow this.Using  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor.
`Thread threadA = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println("A"); });`

`Thread threadB = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println("B"); });`

`Thread threadC = new Thread(() -> { System.out.println("C"); });`

`ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

`executors.submit(threadA);

executors.submit(threadB);

executors.submit(threadC);

executors.shutdown();`

// The answer always A B C

Comment: You can also look up the method of sequential in Stream. follow this: 
` arr.parallelStream().sequential().forEach(//your code );`

Answer (score 0):

Your code *is* indeed "processing" the outer list in parallel and the inner list in sequence. It's just that you are also *printing* the lines in parallel, causing the output to appear out of order.

To fix, you should separate the logic of "processing objects" from "printing objects". Rather than having a `printSublist` that prints a sublist, have a `stringFromSublist` method that given a sublist, returns a string that should be printed for that sublist.

```
private static String stringFromSublist(List<MyObject> innerList) {
    return innerList.stream()
            .map(myObject -> "System Time = "+ 
                             System.nanoTime()+ // nanoTime gives you more resolution
                             " = "+myObject.getName()+
                             " "+myObject.getId())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Now you can use a `map` before `forEachOrdered`:

```
masterList.parallelStream()
    .map(Main::stringFromSublist) // assuming stringFromSublist is in a class called Main
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

The `map` will be parallel. the `forEachOrdered` will be sequential.

Example output:

```
System Time = 20136256197640 = ABC-1 1
System Time = 20136285091800 = ABC-2 2
System Time = 20136285104398 = ABC-3 3
System Time = 20136256536459 = XYZ-1 1
System Time = 20136284789960 = XYZ-2 2
```